# How to pass argument to a subshell (by execute, NOT source) without command line argument?

Tags: shell, parallel-processing, subshell

For example, I have a main shell program `main.sh`, and I have another subshell program `sub.sh`. I want to pass a variable var to the subshell, but I do not want to use command-line argument. An example code is the following:

```
#In main.sh
a=1
./sub.sh

#In sub.sh
echo $a
```

I want to see the output: 1

I know this question is weird, but this feature best suits my need. I can't source the `sub.sh` because in the actual program I have a LOT of variables to pass in... Thanks!

**EDIT**: What if I run `sub.sh` in the backgroun and it takes 10 hours, and I want to run another `sub.sh` in the foreground for another variable `b`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have an extra newline:

```
#In main.sh
a=1 ./sub.sh
```

This is really the same answer as 1_CR, but demonstrates the technique of passing a value to the environment of `sub.sh` instead of modifying the current environment for `sub.sh` to inherit.

Since this is a per-process modification of the environment, you can repeat as necessary.

```
a=1 ./sub.sh &
a=3 b=9 ./sub.sh &
```

Each instance of `sub.sh` sees a different value for `a`, and the second instance sees a value for `b` as well.

Answer (score 3):

You could just export the variable `a`

```
a=1
export a
./sub.sh
```

This causes `a` to be in  the  environment of subsequently executed commands

Comment: What if I run sub.sh in the backgroun and it takes 10 hours, and I want to run another sub.sh in the foreground for another variable b?

Comment: @return0, It sounds like you probably need chepner's solution